# Logitech Mouse MX Master 3S won't connect via bluetooth

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, mouse, logitech

On Ubuntu 22.04 ([MSI Stealth 16 Mercedes-AMG Motorsport A13V](https://de.msi.com/Laptop/Stealth-16-Mercedes-AMG-Motorsport-A13VX) mainboard) I can't connect Logitech Mouse MX Master 3S via bluetooth:

- bluetooth Manager can't see the mouse (other bluetooth devices list fine)
- mouse can connect via Logitech dongle; also works fine via bluetooth in dualbooted Win11 (so no hardware issues with both devices) and also pairs on older laptop with 22.04...
- Solaar doesn't see the mouse either

Any idea?